# Is there any way to get multiple inputs at once using the turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

so i followed a tutorial on learning turtle then made a 2 player ping pong game but i cant seem to make it get the two players move at the same time using listen()

```
window.listen()
window.onkeypress(player_1_move_up, 'w')
window.onkeypress(player_1_move_down, 's')
window.onkeypress(player_2_move_up, "Up")
window.onkeypress(player_2_move_down, "Down")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it upside down, so when you're calling `listen()`, the `onkeypress()` haven't been registered by the program yet.
You could try this instead :

```
window.onkeypress(player_1_move_up, 'w')
window.onkeypress(player_1_move_down, 's')
window.onkeypress(player_2_move_up, "Up")
window.onkeypress(player_2_move_down, "Down")
window.listen()
```

---

If you need to activate 2 functions at once, you could use a wrapper function:

```
def all_move_up(): 
    player_1_move_up() 
    player_2_move_up() 
    
window.onkeypress(all_move_up, 'w')
```

Comment: didn't make a difference sadly

Comment: Could you explain what happens when you press the keys?
Did you try binding 2 functions to the same key?

window.onkeypress(player_1_move_up, 'w')
window.onkeypress(player_2_move_up, 'w')

If that's what you're trying to achieve.

You could use a "wrapper" function:
def all_move_up():
    player_1_move_up()
    player_2_move_up()

window.onkeypress(all_move_up, 'w')

Comment: basically when i hold both player binds one work and the other player freeze also i did have two different funcs for each player

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout this example that works nicely: https://trinket.io/python/16e316e69f

Looking at the code, I noted this line, do you use Screen too ?

```
# Create a variable `screen`, a Screen() object, that will handle keys
screen = turtle.Screen()
```

And later they use *onkey* instead of *onkeypress*, that might just be it:

```
# Tell the program when to move Tina
screen.onkey(tina_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(tina_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(tina_forward, 'Up')
screen.onkey(tina_backward, 'Down')

# Tell the program when to move Tommy
screen.onkey(tommy_left, 'a')
screen.onkey(tommy_right, 'd')
screen.onkey(tommy_forward, 'w')
screen.onkey(tommy_backward, 's')
```

Answer (score 0):

> You could checkout this example that works nicely: https://trinket.io/python/16e316e69f

The program in the link provided allowed for me to move both turtles at the same time. However, when I copied it into my Windows PyCharm (Python 3.9), I can only input one keystroke at a time.

Is this a bug? It seems like its not supposed to work that way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33530311)